# New Design Launched

Tags: discussion, announcements, design

Hi All, as you can see the new design just went live. Which means this site has been officially launched! Congratulations! Thank you for your design [feed back](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257/design-ideas-for-gis-site). I have made some tweaks based on your suggestions.

If you're still seeing the old favicons, please load the following URLs and do a hard browser refresh.

http://sstatic.net/gis/img/favicon.ico

http://sstatic.net/gismeta/img/favicon.ico

If you see any CSS bugs, please start a new post and tag it with "design" and "bug."

Again, congrats!

Comment: Excellent job !

Comment: Very nice design!

Comment: Congratulations Jin!

Comment: Nice work! BTW there was once talk of a domain name... did anything ever come of it?

Comment: @nw1 see this thread: http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/q/3/ basically we decided not to do custom domain names, unless the domain name is exceptionally good.

Answer (score 17):

Looks gorgeous, thanks for all your hard work Jin!

Comment: My pleasure! Thank you for the patience, I'm glad the site is official now!

Comment: So is the GISse out of beta now?

Comment: @Mapperz, yes it is. (:

Comment: Agreed. It looks superb.

Answer (score 2):

Hi Jin,
I really like the site. One quibble though is that I find it a little hard on my eyes. Would it be possible to have greater contrast between the background/foreground? Maybe it's just me, though.

I didn't notice this when I looked at the mockups otherwise I would have mentioned it.

Comment: I agree...it may be age or vision...but otherwise looks great

Comment: I'll adjust the text colors accordingly. btw I assume you were talking about the main site. How's the contrast for you on the Meta site?

Comment: still a bit light, especially in the "related" links to the right and the "help" under the Add comment buttons etc

Comment: yes - I was referring to the main site. The contrast on meta is ok - still a bit light personally. I can read it also, but I do feel with both sites like it's a slight strain (I'm a young person, with glasses for distance).....